# Connect to a virtual machine from outside

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I'm sure that this might have been asked multiple times but after searching over the web I couldn't find an answer to my problem. I'll try to explain the current situation and my problem.

On my current computer, which is running a Windows 10 Professional version, I have installed the VirtualBox and the extensions that allow the RDP.

I have then downloaded the free OS from Microsft that allow the run Virtual Machine for 90 days (available here : https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/ ).

I have then configured it this way for the the "Display" screen : https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtyji.jpg

And this way for the "Network" part : https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4AIM.jpg (the network access is in "Bridge")

After that I've set on my Internet box that the port 25005 should access to the port 25005 or the IP of the Virtual Machine.

By doing that I can connect to the VM localy by using "mstsc 192.168.1.28:25005" but from the outside, when i give my IP to someone else (I don't give them the 192.168.1.28) and they try to connect via mstsc it doesn't work. I have enable the "Allow remote desktop" in the settings of the OS but nothing is happening.

Did I miss something ? Is there something more I have to do ?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

When you mean "outside", I assume you mean outside your LAN / organisation. To answer the questions completely you will need to provide more information.

But as a start you will need a NAT/PAT rule on the device that is managing ACL/routing to allow traffic on port 25005 to 192.168.1.28, if they are trying to connect from outside your organisation. If internal (and using VLAN's), it would be a case of adding a route to the 192.168.1.x subnet. But having more info on your network would help.

PLEASE NOTE - I would be very careful changing/adding any rules to your routers/firewalls unless you know the implications of those rules.

Edit - From your comments, what is required for external users to connect is to use your public IP. You can use https://ipchicken.com/ to determine your public IP address (note - depending on the connection to the ISP, this will mostly likely change unless you pay for a static public IP) 
You will also need an ACL (access control list) to permit traffic from outside your network on port 25005. (this is additional to the NAT rule)

PLEASE NOTE - The ACL would open that port on your network to traffic from the entire web, for better security you should lock down the from traffic to the specific IP or IP range of the external user.

So external users would use publicIP:25005 to connect.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Yes I meant "outside" as ouf of my LAN.

What kind of info you would need ? I've already add a NAT rule that allow the port 25005 to 192.168.1.28 but the only thing it allow me to do was to be able to connect to the VM in LAN not from outside.

Comment: Hi, where did you apply the NAT rule ? (virtualbox vswitch?). Short version is that you need to make sure that there is a route from the "outside". So I need to know where "outside" is exactly in relation to you and a general layout of your network. i.e. Do you have a simple flat network (no vlans) and single route out or is it more complicated ?

Comment: The NAT rule was applied on the interface of my Internet box (on the network configuration tab). To answer your question, i have a simple flat network and a single route. Nothing more complicated (like a simple network organisation of a common house).

Comment: Hi, check the edit to the original answer :)

Comment: Hi, as I said in my main post, the user were already using the external but the result were the same. Regarding the ACL, I don't know where to find that, got any guide or something else ? I've tried many things like downgrading the firewall safety to the lowest on internet box, adding special rules but the result is the same. There is something odd...

Comment: Sorry, misread that part of you post. What is your internet box make, model etc?. I will have a look as and give you some pointers regarding the ACL's.